# WordPress + The Events Calendar Plugin integration with Active Campaign

Tags: wordpress, events, woocommerce

I have events based website (http://techturners.com/seedspot), on which I sell event tickets to customers. I need to integrate these events with active campaign (https://www.activecampaign.com/)

Basically, every time when i add a new event with the help of The Events Calendar Plugin,  the event's details should get added to Active Campaign and somehow tag customers for which event they are registering for.